# The only conjugacy class of the conjugates of a $\textit{p}$-Sylow subgroup $K$ with a single element is $[K]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups, sylow-theory

This question originates from Pinter's Book of Abstract Algebra Chapter 16 exercise N3.

Let $G$ be a finite group, and $K$ a *p*-Sylow subgroup of $G$.  Let $X$ be the set of all the conjugates of $K$.  If $C_1, C_2\in X$, let $C_1\sim C_2$ iff $C_1 = aC_2a^{-1}$ for some $a\in K$. Thus, $\sim$ partitions $X$ into equivalence classes.  If $C\in X$, let the equivalence class of $C$ be denoted by $[C]$. Proves the only class with a single element is $[K]$.

Here is a proof:

Every conjugate of a *p*-Sylow subgroup of $G$ is a *p*-Sylow subgroup of $G$ (by Chapter 16 exercise M2). Thus every element $C\in X$ is a *p*-Sylow subgroup of $G$.

By definition, $[C] = \{aCa^{-1}: a\in K\}$ and $N_K(C) = \{a\in K: aCa^{-1} = C\}$.  Note $N_K(C)$ is a subgroup of $K$ (by Chapter 14 exercise I5).

Let $C^* = \{N_K(C)a: a\in K\}$.  By Chapter 14 exercise I10, $[C]$ is in one-to-one correspondence with $C^*$, and the number of elements in $[C]$ is a divisor of $K$.  In particular, $|[C]| = |C^*| = (K: N_K(C))$, by Lagrange's Theorem.

$a\in K$ implies $a$ has order a power of $p$ (for $K$ is a *p*-Sylow subgroup of $G$), and $aCa^{-1} = C\implies a\in N_K(C)$. It follows $a\in C$, by Chapter 16 exercise M7. Hence, $N_K(C)\subseteq (K\cap C)$.

As $C$ is a conjugate of $K$, $|C| = |K|$ (by Chapter 14 exercise I2).  It's easy to see that $|[K]| = 1$ (as $aKa^{-1} = K$ for all $a\in K$).  Suppose $C\ne K$.  Then $(K\cap C)\subset K$, and therefore $|N_K(C)| < |K|$. It follows that $|[C]| = (K: N_K(C)) > 1$.

Does it look right?  Is there a simpler proof?

Comment: Who is acting on $X$? The way I read it, the obvious reading is that $G$ is acting on $X$, but in that case the problem is wrong. Is there an indication that it is $K$ who is doing the acting?

Comment: Interesting point.  I've added more background info to the original question (which is part of a series of exercises.)

Comment: Okay, so, yes, you have $K$ acting on $X$.

Comment: Your proof is correct. I'm not sure if there is a simpler one, but you could have used the Orbit-Stabilizer theorem more explicitly and saved a few lines. You have $K$ acting on $X$ with the rule $a\star C = aCa^{-1}$, for all $(a,C)\in K\times X$. Then for each $C\in X$, $[C]=Orb(C)$, and $Stab(C)=\{a\in K: aCa^{-1}=C\}$. Proving $[K]=\{K\}$ is simple, so it's really just a matter of showing that $Stab(C)$ is a proper subgroup of $K$ whenever $C\neq K$. You already know $Stab(C)$ is a subgroup of $K$, for all $C\in X$, so you just need to show that $Stab(C)\subset K$.